# Android "jsonObject.getString" replaces "/" to "\/" in json object

Tags: android, json

I am using `jsonObject.getString` to get json string of specific value inside json string and it replaces character `'/'` to `"\/"` how to prevent that ?

**example:** 
`"QCqBtmqoQZiUghFOk/OxRg=="`, recieved as `"QCqBtmqoQZiUghFOk\/OxRg=="`

Comment: It cannot be prevented because / is special character. Why You need to prevent it?

Comment: If you really want it: `yourString = jsonObject.getString().replace("\\/", "/");`

Comment: @anhtuannd thank you it works well

Answer (score 3):

try may be help you

```
   String deft = dictionary.getString("Definitions");
   deft = deft.replace("\"", "");
```